# Interchanging Limits: $a_{n,k}\to C$ implies $\sum_k^n a_{n,k}b_k\to C\sum_k^\infty b_k$?

Tags: general-topology, limits, topological-vector-spaces

> Consider a doubly-indexed sequence $(a_{n,k})$ which, for each $k$, converges as $n\to\infty$ to an absolute constant $C$. In what generality can we say that for a sequence $b_k$
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n a_{n,k}b_k = C\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k \quad?$$

Motivation: I am doing a combinatorics homework assignment and we have been asked to prove something related to $q$-Pochhammer symbols, so my question arose specifically from a very nice notion of convergence (formal power series), and an extremely simple $b_k$:
$$ a_{n,k}=\binom{2n}{n+k}_q \to (q;q)_\infty \qquad\qquad b_k =x^k.$$

I'm more or less convinced that I can do this in my example, because you can reason that the $x$ and $q$ are algebraically independent and so you can just get away with comparing coefficients. This is basically a slightly more advanced version of "convergence in each coordinate".

However, actually proving this always comes down to one or two steps that I am sure are true but feel rather uncomfortable stating. I know that one can interpret a formal power series ring as a topological vector space, and I think the gold standard would be to prove it in this setting (take $a_{n,k}$ to be scalars and $b_k$ to be vectors) for any sequence $b_k$. Perhaps we would need to restrict it to a sequence with convergent series; that's fine.

To me this does seem rather likely. I know it's generically dangerous to pull out a limit from a summation sign, and topological vector spaces are particularly weird. But the fact that the constant is universal (not dependent on $k$) makes me feel that some sort of uniformity may save the day.

Comment: Are your constants positive (or more generally, is the sum absolutely convergent).

Comment: Maybe. I don't know a notion of absolute convergence in $\Bbb C(q)[[x]]$, for instance. For my motivation, I had that each rational function of $q$ is actually a polynomial with positive coefficients; this is about 'as positive as you can get' in this setting.

Comment: you have to group/split the terms of the series such that it becomes absolutely convergent. and I don't understand your $a_{n,k}$ sequence, what is $q$ ? and if you can compare the coefficients it is because you consider in fact a sequence of functions converging to another function

Comment: In the motivating example, $q$ is a variable. Perhaps it was not clear that 'comparing coefficients' there meant $x$-coefficients. In the motivating example, I certainly was hoping that we could get a sequence of 'functions' converging to another 'function' to the extent that FPSs are functions, which is why I thought of the $b_k$ as vectors in a TVS.